# Mobile media query, resolution and ppi simulator?

Tags: css, responsive-design, ppi, device-width

Are there any sorts of desktop tools or browser plugins that are able to simulate various mobile and tablet devices in order to properly test responsive designs? And I'm not just talking about changing the browser window size. Other items would need to be simulated as well:

- device-width
- min-device-width
- max-device-width
- orientation (landscape/portrait)
- -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio
- resolution
- ppi

Comment: I've found this very helpful, but it's more of a browser size tool. http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr Try it out. If you do end up testing on physical hardware there is adobe shadow http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/

Answer (score 0):

I typically try [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/). It's fairly accurate, and will imitate high DPI displays, etc, and will handle most the media queries just fine. Just pick your display characteristics, or a device to emulate, and it will attempt to render in that manner.